# How to write files to Sharepoint online using Azure Service Principle for authentication via Databricks?

Tags: azure, databricks, sharepoint-online

I've a databricks code which writes files to Sharepoint online using my personal AD credentials for authentication. However I'm not allowed to use my personal AD credentials for security reasons and password expires ever 90 days.

With that said I explored options such as getting a Service account created but that was not possible due to licensing issues.

Are there other possibilities to approach this?
Is it possible to use Azure Service Principle for authentication? If yes could you please advise how to achieve this?

Comment: it really depends on what library/code are you using to write that data

Comment: I am using Python's shareplum library to write to Sharepoint.